# Building form that can be reused everywhere in HTML code

Tags: jquery, html, forms, function

First of all I am a beginner-level UI developer.

I have a form that I want to enable it several places in my code [it would be great if I can give this via js file so anyone can use it with few lines of code].

In side form I have a single textarea, submit button and cancel button. 
When user clicks submit, I would like to send content to Yammer wall via API.

I want to use this code in multiple objects in my code with some parameters

i.e. someFunctionName(widgetName, widgetData) will display a image and when the user click on the image it will show a textarea so that user can submit message [message will use two string parameters in function] or cancel will hide form.

How can I achieve this. Simple code would be great instead of sending to API you can just alert message [message is widgetName + widgetData + value in related textarea]

I share my code I wrote so far but I know it's not even close to what I want.

Thanks in advance

```
       <html>
   <head>
       <title>A Yammer App</title>
       <script src="https://assets.yammer.com/platform/yam.js"></script>
    <script>
      yam.config({appId: "app-id-for-yammer"});
    </script>

<style type="text/css">

.yammertext {
  margin: 2px; width: 328px; height: 32px;
}


.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <script>
    function post() {
        yam.getLoginStatus( function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                yam.request(
                  { url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json"
                  , method: "POST"
                  , data: { "body" : "Test yammer API - ED"}
                  , success: function (msg) { alert("Post was Successful!: " + msg); }
                  , error: function (msg) { alert("Post was Unsuccessful..." + msg); }
                  }
                );
            } else {
                yam.login( function (response) {
                  if (!response.authResponse) {
                    yam.request(
                      { url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json"
                      , method: "POST"
                      , data: { "body" : "Test yammer API - ED"}
                      , success: function (msg) { alert("Post was Successful!: " + msg); }
                      , error: function (msg) { alert("Post was Unsuccessful..." + msg); }
                      }
                    );
                  }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    </script>


 <script type="text/javascript">

 function post2(a) {
      alert(a);
    }

</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{

$("#content").focus(function()
{
$(this).animate({"height": "85px",}, "fast" );
$("#button_block").slideDown("fast");
return false;
});

$("#cancel").click(function()
{
$("#content").animate({"height": "30px",}, "fast" );
$("#button_block").slideUp("fast");
return false;
});

});
</script>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});

</script>


<a href="#" class="show_hide">Yammer</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <textarea  id="content" class="yammertext"></textarea>
    <div id="button_block">
      <input type="submit" id="button" value=" Share " onclick="post2(this)"/>
      <input type="submit" id='cancel' value=" cancel" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you create its template and use it as many times as you like!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what do you mean by template. Would mind exlaining with an example?

Comment: take a look at http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: You can create a template of your in java-scrip which will return the final html then you will be able to append it anywhere!

Comment: Why must your comment end in exclamation marks!

Answer (score 0):

IF you use a server side scripting language. You can a html file with your form it then include it where you would like. This would mean you only need one line of code to place your form.

EG in PHP this would be

```
<?php include 'filename'; ?>
```

Or if you want you could use the jQuery .load() function to load in your HTML file

```
$("#DivNAme").load("Filename.html");
```